# Build Error: while running worker Role in local system

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-worker-roles

I am new to Azure Worker Role ,I have created a new Azure Cloud Service project and added a  worker role.In which I have a thread that makes function call to sampledll where I am creating EventHub listener.

I found error like below.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The process cannot access the file 'D:\Azure\roles\simpleWorkerRole\approot\sampledll.dll' because it is being used by another process. simpleWorkerRole.WorkerRole C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets  1057
```

Answer (score 0):

> The process cannot access the file 'D:\Azure\roles\simpleWorkerRole\approot\sampledll.dll' because it is being used by another process.

The error message indicates the sampledll.dll is being used by another process, you could try to use [Process Monitor tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to find which process is using (or locking) sampledll.dll and then you could manually end the process and rebuild the solution.